# grouping anything between two character using regx python

Tags: python

i have a pattern like below.

```
this.RANGE.configure(this, 5, 0, "RO", 0, 5'h0, 1, 0, 1);
```

RANGE,5,0,"RO",0,5'h0,1,0,1 are variables few are strings and few are integers here.

How to write a regular expression which groups anything between two . or two commas for example to extract all this info?

Comment: `a good way to do this ?` - Read up on regular expressions and experiment with patterns at an online regex tester like  https://regex101.com/  - but you can [split a string](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/stdtypes.html#str.split) on any character without using a regular expression.

Comment: [Formatting posts](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) ... [Formatting help](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help)

Answer (score 0):

For example,

```
p = re.compile(",[^,]*,")
p.findall(s)
```

Finds all strings between two commas but not containing a third comma, including the two commas. You can then strip the commas from the beginning and end. The same approach works for periods.

Unfortunately, `findall` does not include duplicates, so for that you would need to loop through and use `search` instead.

Comment: How about `',([^,]*),'`?